# How to prevent browser startup on network change?

Tags: windows-10

I'm behind corporate proxy. Windows running in virtual machine. Host is Mac.

Everytime I change network from ethernet to wifi and vice versa MS Edge starting up and asking me about proxy settings. Because of corporate policy I don't want Windows to remember my password (my account will be blocked) and I don't want it to pops up everytime.

I read somewhere that windows performs network availability checking and if password is required it opens browser so I can type it.

Question is - how to get rid of this behaviour?

Comment: Typically, there will be domain Group Policy settings that push out the LAN proxy server address and port... but then again, it is rather uncommon to see a Mac on a domain, also.

Comment: Windows VM is not in active directory so group policies are not applied.

Comment: If you manually enter the  LAN proxy server address and port within Internet Explorer (Internet Options > Connections tab > LAN settings button), it doesn't retain them?